# Cell division problem - how to fix this glitch?

Tags: dynamic-paint

I have a problem splitting a cell in two when using dynamic paint modifier > Surface > Waves, to emphasize the "wobble" effect.

I tried to follow this youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTgd25Llh1M&t=110s, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

When dynamic paint modifier is used I get this weird glitch when the cells separate and the sphere in between pulls the cells inwards not outwards.

My version:

[image]

The correct version:

[image: How it looks in my project vs how it should look.]

[image: Cell canvas]

[image: Sphere brush]

Project file - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1POV717YKjfdwmQfYf78vX8v4gke1LWhd/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Nice method. Are you working to scale, and have you copied the settings in the tutorial as far as you can see them? The  small sphere is the Brush for your DPaint.. what are the settings on that?

Comment: Hey, I'm probably not working to scale, not sure what are the parameters in the tutorial - might be the part of the problem? I'm also attaching my DPaint settings and project file.